NextJS middleware keeps redirecting to localhost:3000 but I'm using 127.0.0.1:3000
I’m working on a project using Next.js middleware for authentication. My app runs on 127.0.0.1:3000, and the backend (FastAPI) is configured to set cookies for 127.0.0.1. Everything works fine until a redirect happens in the middleware.
The issue: when the middleware redirects an authenticated user to another route,  the browser’s Location header in the redirect response changes from http://127.0.0.1:3000 to http://localhost:3000.
And because localhost and 127.0.0.1 are treated as different domains, the cookies tied to 127.0.0.1 are no longer sent with requests, and the user appears unauthenticated.
This causes the user to be redirected back to the login page but on localhost
and not 127.0.0.1 where they should have been redirected to.
Things to note:
The cookies are set correctly for 127.0.0.1 with these attributes:
domain=127.0.0.1 SameSite=Lax HttpOnly=true
Despite explicitly building the redirect URL in middleware with 127.0.0.1, the Location header in the response shows http://localhost:3000.
middleware.ts:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(request) {
    const protocol = request.nextUrl.protocol || 'http';
    const host = request.headers.get('host'); // Get the actual host
    const redirectUrl = `${protocol}//${host}/services/patient/search`;

    const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value;

    if (token) {
      console.log("User is authenticated. Redirecting to:", redirectUrl);
      return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl);
    }

    console.log("User is not authenticated. Proceeding...");
    return NextResponse.next();
}

The redirectUrl is dynamically constructed using request.headers.get('host'), which correctly resolves to 127.0.0.1:3000.but, the browser still redirects to localhost:3000.

Dynamically building the redirect URL using request.headers.get('host') to match the incoming host.

Updating the dev script in my package.json to explicitly bind the Next.js development server to 127.0.0.1:


"dev": "next dev -H 127.0.0.1 -p 3000"

Clearing cookies and browser caches for both localhost and 127.0.0.1.

Ensuring backend cookies are explicitly set with domain=127.0.0.1.

Testing in incognito mode to rule out caching issues.



which browser? chrome (based on incognito remark)

yes I'm using Chrome @benc

I think you've isolated the problem to the middleware, but how much do you want to hack at it? You could edit the /etc/hosts file on the server (super dangerous, but depends on if you are booting on host OS or not), or you do packet trace to see if it is doing name lookup.
